# How to Add to Current Value in MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a DB Entry that only consists of a number. and i want to Make it where users on my site can Exchange from One to the Other and i know how to do all that but i dont wanna Replace 
the current value i just wanna add for example 1,000 to it what code can i use in PHP ?

Answer (score 25):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE `some_table` SET `value` = `value` + 1000 WHERE `id` = 1");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

update like this

Answer (score 18):

if you have a value in some table in some database all you have to do is to issue an update statement for that fields.

For example, lets say we have table like this

```
+--------------+
| some_table   |
+--------------+
| id   | value |
+--------------+
| 1    | 10    |
+--------------+
```

So your update will be as follows:

```
UPDATE `some_table` SET `value` = `value` + 1000 WHERE `id` = 1
```

See more info on how to [execute mysql queries with php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: Also if i want to Subtract a Value from the Value do i just change + to - ?

Comment: yes, you can perform most math funtions like add, subtract, multiply, divide, even perform function calls to mutate the value